# Can a magnet damage a compass?

Tags: electromagnetism

I've heard the claim before that a magnet can ruin a compass, and was about to repeat it to my son when I realized it sounds like complete nonsense.  Googling turned up such [unsubstantiated and illogical answers as this one](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110112122537AAhYAdW) and [unanswered questions as this one](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Will_a_magnet_ruin_a_compass) but nothing that sounded reasonable to me and gave a convincing explanation.  Perhaps my Google bubble is at work.

Anyway, since SE is generally very reliable, I thought this was the right place to ask, before I pass on untested nonsense to my son.  Help me break the chain of untested pseudoscience via oral tradition:  does a magnet actually do permanent damage to a compass, or just temporarily prevent it from detecting magnetic north?

If it actually *does* do this, please explain how that is so.

Comment: A magnet can disturb a compass, but only temporary, since a compass is a magnet aligning to the magnetic field of earth. To actually damage it, that sounds VERY strange. I guess someone have misunderstood something and spread it along.

Comment: How heavy is the magnet?

Comment: For purposes of discussion, assume a strong rare-earth magnet.  I know that's vague, but if it's possible for an extremely strong magnet to damage a compass, then it *is* possible.  If it takes a ridiculously strong magnet to have an effect, then that should be part of the answer.

Comment: I dunno, I don't think a magnet would affect your ability to [draw circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_%28drafting%29) at all :)

Comment: @Wertliq: Funny. My first thought was "Yes, of course it could damage a compass, depending of the coercitivity of the needle." but then I remembered the compass needle is free spinning, so it would presumably be difficult to stroke the external magnet against its field... which lead to the conclusion I shouldn't speculate about theory, but should find some empirical results.

Comment: I've heard this too. My recollection is that the claims are: (a) demagnetizes needle; (b) can induce permanent magnetic field in other metallic parts of the assembly containing the compass, such as a steel case, disrupting compass accuracy.  But I have not tried to research this at all.

Comment: @Paul: okay, that at least sounds slightly plausible, which is more than I can say for anything else I've found.

Comment: I have to say that it happens, event though I have no idea why. Like iconoclast said, if you store a strong rare-earth magnet with the compass then the compass will get screwed up. I know this because I work for a kids outreach program and we got problems with some of the compasses because of this. But as for how, I haven't done enough research into this personally.

Comment: +1 for catching yourself before repeating it to your son.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Depending upon the coercivity of the needle, a sufficiently strong magnet wouldn't need to be "stroked" against it, but could reset the magnetic domains all at once.  Since a typical compass needle is only free to rotate about one axis, the domains could get set to an angle which is not parallel to the needle.  I think it would be safe to say that at least some compasses (if nothing else, the toy ones found in popcorn-snack boxes) could be rendered useless by strong magnets, but some compasses might be immune to damage from the strongest known as-yet-invented permanent-magnets.

Comment: I have a compass that had it's polarity flipped by being stored in my wife's purse.  We suspect it was the field from the cell phone it was up against.

Comment: I made a south-pointing compass once: take a cheap compass and a strong permanent magnet.  Place the compass so that the needle is pointing at a pole of the magnet.  Now, flip the magnet so fast that the compass needle's inertia prevents it from turning to match the magnet's new orientation.  You've now got a south-pointing compass.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes a magnet can damage a compass.

The compass needle is a [ferromagnetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism) material.

The degree to which a ferromagnetic material can "withstand an external magnetic field without becoming demagnetized" is referred to as its [coercivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coercivity).

Another magnet near the compass needle imposes a magnetic field upon the compass needle. It is a matter of the strength of the magnetic field imposed upon the compass needle and the coercivity of the needle material whether or not the magnetic properties of the compass needle are damaged.

Comment: I would just add that it is possible that the ferromagnetic needle will be magnetized in the opposite direction, if the field was strong enough(thus flipping north and south for the user).

Comment: A related question - would it be permanent? That is, can it be reversed with the correct procedure, with/without having to rebuild the compass. Context is always helpful: say you're Jerry Seinfeld, and you just ruined a Navy Seal's expensive compass with a magnet, and need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

If the field is big enough it can physically destroy the compass needle. But that might be the least of your problems at that point

Answer (score 0):

A magnet is made by aligning the magnetic poles of all the molecules in a magnetic material so they all point the same way.
If you have a look at how a magnet is made, traditionally 
http://www.princeton.edu/ssp/joseph-henry-project/permanent-magnet/ 
or commercially 
http://www.arnoldmagnetics.com/Magnet_Manufacturing_Process.aspx 
you will see it is made by applying a magnetic field to a magnetic material in which these molecules are able to move (either a fine powder in modern manufacturing or a ductile/malleable material). 
Equally you can reverse the process, immersing a material whose molecules are able to move (like a metal, but not most sintered magnets which are held in crystal lattice)  in a magnetic field that is not aligned with its existing field will cause the molecules to move, REMOVING the alignment and hence the existing magnetization. 
Or in other words - yes - you can even reverse the compass if you try hard enough.

Edit - i noticed a comment that the compass needle can move and hence align itself with the external magnetic field, but of course a compass has only one degree of freedom of motion and can only align itself on that axis. Many are also unable to rotate freely unless held in an upright position.

Answer (score 0):

I am a neodymium magnet sales for many years,in fact the magnets won't damage the compass,but it will influence the compass.
All of magnets are permanent magnets,the earliest compass is found in China and use ferrite magnet.The ferrite performance is very stable,so it can be used for more than 2 thousand years and also used in many speaker equipment. Even though the magnets in compass have a little broken,the compass also can work normally.But if you put a extra magnet close to compass，the two magnets will make a new magnetic field, originally the two single magnet exist their own magnetic filed,but they influence each other to cause a new magnetic field when the compass work wrong way, but you only should take away the magnet from compass，the compass will become normal.

Comment: I've removed your link, since purchasing one of your magnets won't help to answer this question. Your [user profile](http://physics.stackexchange.com/users/141429/benny-chen) is a more appropriate place for such links.

Comment: The link does actually lend some credence to the claim that he is involved in sales of magnets, but yes I guess a user profile is still a better place for that.